# iOS 11 dropInteraction performDrop for files

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, ios11

How can I use `dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession)` to accept other type of files than images? Say for instnce that I drag a PDF or MP3 from the files app. How can I accept this file and get the data?

I thought I could use NSURL.self, but that only seems to work for URL's dragged from Safari och a textview.

Answer (score 13):

An example for PDF (*com.adobe.pdf* UTI) implementing `NSItemProviderReading` could be something like this:

```
class PDFDocument: NSObject, NSItemProviderReading {
    let data: Data?

    required init(pdfData: Data, typeIdentifier: String) {
        data = pdfData
    }

    static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
        return [kUTTypePDF as String]
    }

    static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> Self {
        return self.init(pdfData: data, typeIdentifier: typeIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Then in your delegate you need to handle this PDFDocument:

```
extension YourClass: UIDropInteractionDelegate {
    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: PDFDocument.self))
    }

    .
    .
    .

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
        session.loadObjects(ofClass: PDFDocument.self) { [unowned self] pdfItems in
            if let pdfs = pdfItems as? [PDFDocument], let pdf = pdfs.first {
                // Whatever you want to do with the pdf
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this but keep getting crash...did you managed to get it to work?

Comment: Hm, have you tried dragging from the Files app? I keep getting libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

P.S – If i drag from an online example PDF it works. Just not from the Files app?

Comment: What do you have in the `dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession)
` ??

Comment: how would you get the selected file name and location?

Answer (score 2):

Within `dropInteraction` you call `session.loadObjects(ofClass:)`, which you probably already have, and have tried `UIImage` and `NSURL`.

`ofClass` needs to conform to `NSItemProviderReading` ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemproviderreading)). The default classes that conform to it are `NSString`, `NSAttributedString`, `NSURL`, `UIColor`, and `UIImage`. For anything else, I think you will need to make a custom class conforming to the protocol, using `public.mp3` as the [UTI](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html). Your custom class will have a `init(itemProviderData: Data, typeIdentifier: String)` initializer that should give you a bag of bytes (`itemProviderData`) that is the MP3s data. From there, you should be able to write out your file as needed.