# iOS 11 drag and drop custom files?

Tags: ios, ipad

Has anyone gotten custom files to drag and drop in iOS 11? There are tons of examples of the standard images and text, but what about custom files? Even standard files like PDF would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

- Method 1:

make a `PDFDocument` class and implements the `NSObject, NSItemProviderReading` protocol, then we just change the `UIImage` to `PDFDocument` class in those tons of examples

more detail here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45982118/3608824

- Method 2:

Another way is since we have this `kUTTypePDF` Uniform Type Identifier , as long as you `import MobileCoreServices`, according to [dropInteraction(_:performDrop:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidropinteractiondelegate/2890889-dropinteraction?changes=latest_beta) document, we can use this function `loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier:completionHandler:)`, something like this should work:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: [kUTTypePDF as String]) && session.items.count == 1
}

func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
    return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
}

func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    if let itemProvider = (session.items.first)?.itemProvider {
        itemProvider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypePDF as String) { (data, error) in
            // do the work
        }
    }

}
```