# NSItemProviderReading on Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios11

To do files drag & drop for files in iOS 11 you need to implement `NSItemProviderReading`, there is the sample code for swift here: [iOS 11 dropInteraction performDrop for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494871/ios-11-dropinteraction-performdrop-for-files)

However, how to do that in Xamarin, I guess the class definition should look like this, but how to implement the methods?

```
public class DocumentProvider : NSObject, INSItemProviderReading
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `NSItemProviderReading` like this:

```
class MyItemProvider : UIView, INSItemProviderReading {

    [Export ("readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider")]
    public static string [] ReadableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider => new string [] { "public.image", "public.data" }

    [Export ("objectWithItemProviderData:typeIdentifier:error:")]
    public static MyItemProvider GetObject (NSData data, string typeIdentifier, out NSError outError)
    {
        outError = null;
        switch (typeIdentifier) {
        case "public.image": return new ...;
        case "public.data": return new ...;
        default:
            outError = new NSError (...);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:[NSItemProviderReading requirements](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57735).

Comment: It is partially useful, but as it seems that you can't create an instance of the class in its static method it doesn't work...